# tabBarVisible not working in createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native

i use from createBottomTabNavigator and i want to hide a screen( or tab) and tabBarVisible: false not working for me

```
 export default createBottomTabNavigator(
{
factor_inquirys:{
    screen:FactorInquirysScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title:strings.factor_inquirys,
        header:null,
        tabBarVisible: false
    }
}
```

so thanks for help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The prop `tabBarVisible` is not used to hide a tabBarItem from the tabBar.

`tabBarVisible` will hide the whole bottomTabNavigator from the screen it's defined in. So, if you go to `factor_inquirys`, you will see that the tabBar will not be displayed.

If you want to hide a specific tab in createBottomTabNavigator, you have to create a custom `tabBarComponent` and add some logic to it hiding a specific tab